# NT75451 LCD with STM32

Tags: microcontroller, glcd, stm32f3

I am using STM32F303VCT6 microcontroller for my application. My question is: **Are there any libraries for the GLCD NT75451 which may help me display geometric shapes on the screen?**

**FYI : LCD interface is parallel with micro-controller.**

Answer (score 1):

The [emWin](http://www.segger.com/emwin.html) library from Segger can do it. STM32 users have a free license to use it from ST (see [here](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1734/PF259225)). It supports geometric shapes as you requested, but I should mention you can also make full GUIs with buttons, sliders, text boxes, etc.

Unfortunately, according to this [application note](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/application_note/DM00089670.pdf), only two sets of drivers are available with the free ST version: `GUIDRV_FlexColor` and `GUIDRV_Lin`. Seems like `GUIDRV_SPage` would be the driver of choice for your controller, but it's not available on the free version. You have a choice of writing your own driver or buying the full library from Segger, which includes the driver you need. Writing your own driver is no big deal (I've written one myself for another controller), especially if you have prior experience with it, or working example code available. Of course, if you have the budget for it, buying the full version would save a lot of effort and mean less time to market (assuming you're doing this professionally and not as a hobby).